He is as honest a man as I've ever met


He is as honest a man as I've ever met. (from my dicitonary)


I wonder if the first 'as' can be so'.


He is so honest a man as I've ever met.


Edit note:
What's the meaning of sentence 1?

No, your suggestion is not idiomatic.

"So" in that context implies a comparison or example follows, e.g., "He is so honest, he returned the extra item."

What leads you to think that so might work? You know by now that posts here ought to include descriptions of the good faith efforts one has made to work out their answers on one’s own.

I might say this kind of question is hard for non-native learners could deal with on their own.

(1) means "I have never met a man more honest than he is" (he is as honest as the most honest man I have met).

Where the superative meaning comes from?

Please try to use the right form: Where does the superlative meaning come from?

@gomadeng, I would have never thought such a stucture (1) would be correct, based on what we were taught so far. Unfortunately, such rare and advanced structures are not covered in grammer lessons for learner. So it is good that you have asked it.

@PaulTanenbaum Sometimes so and as are interchangeable: She was not so/as beautiful as I imagined.

@Yunus That's right it's an advanced construction using 'as ... as' to represent a superative meaning: as+adj.+a/an+noun as+perfect tense. The more difficult constructions we learn, the less difficult constructions we have.

The sentence means that he's among the most honest people the speaker has ever met. It's a shortened form of

He's as honest a man as [any other man] I've ever met.

While "X is as Y as Z" would normally mean that X and Z have the same level of Y (e.g. "the light was as bright as the sun"), when we say "as any Z" it usually means we're comparing with the most extreme examples of Z, unless there's some reason to believe that all Z have the same Y quality.

Thx 4 answer and your math.
